# what's the reason for the ARP is running while trying the ping command?

Tags: ping, wireshark, arp

when i try **ping** command and when i see it in **wireshark** first **ARP request**  is going and after the **ARP** reply only **ICMP request** is going ,

i think this is what the reason for the ARP request going in the first,,

while trying **ping** it need to know the **MAC** address of the target device,
so its trying to the get the MAC address first and then its sending **ICMP request**

if that is true is it possible to mention the mac address in the ping command(not to try for ARP)

if that is not true what's the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll note that the ARP request only happens the first time you run `ping`.  If you run it a second time (shortly after the first run), you'll see that the `ping` start immediately with an ICMP request.  This is because when a system discovers the IP address/MAC address association via ARP, it stores the result in a local [arp cache](http://www.petri.co.il/csc_arp_cache.htm).  Entries in the cache do expire after some amount of time.

You can manually populate the ARP cache using the `arp` command:

```
arp -s <ipaddr> <macaddr>
```

E.g.:

```
arp -s 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1
```

You can see the contents of your ARP cache like this:

```
arp -an
```

So if you were to manually update the ARP cache with the MAC address of your target host, you would be able to ping it with an ARP request going over the network.